# Is there any way to get rid of the 'infinity' button in Cookie Clicker?

Tags: cookie-clicker

I let my friend use my computer, and she wanted to play cookie clicker after I showed her. I left to go to the bathroom, and when I came back, she had hacked the game so it said infinity in the place where the number of cookies usually goes. Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either:

Fully wipe your save, achieved by going to Options > Wipe save, shown below:

[image: How to wipe your save]

Or, assuming the only thing they changed was the amount of cookies you had, press F12 (Chrome) or Ctrl+Shift+K (Firefox) to enter the console, and type `Game.cookies = 0` to set your game's cookies to 0. You can change that number to whatever you want if you want to reverse the changes.

[image: The console, with two Game.cookies commands typed in]

Keep in mind that modifying `Game.cookies` will grant you the Shadow Achievement "Cheated cookies taste awful", so if you don't want that, you'll have to wipe your save.